# Lowerdir Directory Installation

Tags: system-installation, directory

Alright.I am trying to recover from a system crash.I am aware what lowerdir is and does to some extent and I recieve a message that the directory is missing, and I dont have a lock screen upon boot.This occurs on the typical bootlog when the OS starts.May anyone explain how to reinstall the directory because I had no luck on Google (Not surprised being honest), and potentially give a guide on how to bring back the lock screen? Again, I am not familiar with Overlaysf and Upperdir/Lowerdir so this would be a major help.Thanks =)

Ps: Im running Hirsute.

Answer (score 0):

If the message you are seeing is this:

```
overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
```

Then your disk is full and you'll need to boot in recovery mode (or with a Live USB / DVD) and delete some unnecessary files. This could be the result of excessive logs in `/var/log` or just about anything else that might fill a storage device to capacity.

Once the device has enough free storage you should be able to boot into the graphical interface again.

Comment: I am having this error, but my disk is definitely not full. Is there a different cause for this error?

Comment: @Ralff there are two definitions of full that can cause this: (1) no more blocks to write the data (2) no more inodes to record file information to. The first happens when you have lots of large files while the latter happens with lots of little files. If neither of these are applicable, feel free to create a new question with as much detail about your situation. Perhaps someone will have an answer 